# Select box's odd behavior on doing add items from another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, dom-events

I am facing a strange behavior on select box after adding some items into it. In my code snippet below, if I click on Insert options, items in select becomes non selectable or disabled. 
I am using IE11 browser, but this is working fine in Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>

<p>Click the button to add a "Kiwi" option at the end of the dropdown list.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
    x[3].text=x[2].text
    x[3].value=x[2].value
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working the same in IE and Chrome for me..

Comment: Any errors appear in Console?

Comment: @Mosh, which version in IE u tried?.....it will work in chrome....but in IE 11 version, it wont work....however no errors...

Comment: and the strange solution I have is: it will work when i use statement : oTgt.options[nJ + 1].innerText= oTgt.options[nJ].text; where I used "innerText" instead of "text" property for Option object. But I dont know the  reason why?

Comment: I tried in IE11. Actually I don't fimiliar with `.text` property at all. Maybe tha's the reason. It's not cross platforn..

Comment: yeah but .text is working with other browsers at the same time, I think it works in chrome, firefox and older versions of IE. Actually I want to justify ".innerText" instead of ".text"....in that case.

Comment: am wondering am not getting any good respone for this post which is half day old.and the issue is easily reproducible in IE11.

Comment: Where are the geeks in stack overflow? I think I need to put this issue in some other forum to get an answer. Even I put this issue, with a reproducing example, am not getting any inputs for one week old post. Let me post this some where other forum, will update here if I get an answer...Why am saying this, I have an impression with this forum to get real quick solutions, but now it lost!!!